# Should it be "expand" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

This is a line I came across in someone's bio. Apparently the author is not a native speaker of English. The verb **extend** strikes me as somewhat unusual. Although **extend** has the sense *cause to cover a larger area*, I am not sure one can *extend* research to an area. Does **expand** work better in this sentence? Or are both verbs fine?

> Since 2005 I have **extended** my research on education to the German society.

Comment: **Extended** is fine in this context. **Expanded** would also work but doesn't mean quite the same thing.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extended

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you. I have looked at M-W and Oxford dictionaries before posting. My doubt comes from the fact that there's multiple entries in those dictionaries that appear close in meaning to the usage at issue, but I am not quite sure they cover the usage I am wondering about. Would you elaborate on the difference **expand** would have in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I write as a native BrE speaker. There is a difference in meaning between extend and expand in this context, but it is a subtle one that I can best illustrate with an example from my own research.

I am researching how to solve a particular statistical problem. I have today realised that to solve this problem I have to examine some subjects that I had not previously considered relevant. I have **extended** my research.

Having solved my problem, called for the purposes of illustration "statistical properties of left-handed screwdrivers", I now realise that very similar techniques would also sove the related but different problem of right-handed screwdrivers. I have **expanded** my research.

Answer (score 1):

Both "extend" and "expand" are fine in this context.  One metaphorically indicates *stretching out* in a particular direction, while the other indicates *widening the range* to include a new area.

In a similar way you can *extend* a structure by adding on a new room, increasing its length.  You can also *expand* the structure in the same way, increasing its area.  It's two ways of describing the same result.